# Keras error 'Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am currently trying to make a research paper's source code work. It's supposed to be able to detect cells on an image using deep learning. The source code is available here : https://github.com/WeidiXie/cell_counting_v2

I'm using Python 3.9.5 and keras 2.5.0.

I've been having some issues trying to make this code work properly, I am getting errors that I'm not sure how to resolve. This happens when I compile train.py :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Fac\Stage L2\Travail\train.py", line 126, in <module>
train_(base_path)

File "D:\Fac\Stage L2\Travail\train.py", line 87, in train_model = buildModel_U_net(input_dim = (256,256,3))

File "D:\Fac\Stage L2\Travail\model.py", line 173, in buildModel_U_net
act_ = U_net_base (input_, nb_filter = 64 )

File "D:\Fac\Stage L2\Travail\model.py", line 123, in U_net_baseblock1 = _conv_bn_relu_x2(nb_filter,3,3)(input)

File "D:\Fac\Stage L2\Travail\model.py", line 57, in fconv_a = Convolution2D(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = subsample,

File "C:\Users\Cinna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 656, in __init__super(Conv2D, self).__init__(

File "C:\Users\Cinna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 125, in __init__
super(Conv, self).__init__(

File "C:\Users\Cinna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Cinna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 323, in __init__
generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Cinna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 1134, in validate_kwargs
raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')
```

From my understanding, there's an issue with the parameters on line 57 in model.py, they are not recognized ;

```
conv_a = Convolution2D(nb_filter, row, col, subsample = subsample,
                           init = 'orthogonal', border_mode = 'same',bias = False,
                           W_regularizer = l2(weight_decay),
                           b_regularizer = l2(weight_decay))(input)
```

I found out if I modified keras configuration's file base_layer.py and added more "acceptable" parameters in the list on line 312 I wouldn't get those errors anymore, but it seems weird that this would be the way to go

```
    allowed_kwargs = {
    'input_dim',
    'input_shape',
    'batch_input_shape',
    'batch_size',
    'weights',
    'activity_regularizer',
    #'subsample',
    #'init',
    #'border_mode',
    #'bias',
    #'W_regularizer',
    #'b_regularizer',
    'autocast',
    'implementation',
}
```

I'd prefer to only modify the source code on the project and not kera's, I just don't understand how. There's got to be a reason these keywords aren't in the configuration file, but how am I supposed to make it work then ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because of version mismatch of Keras. `Convolution2D` is a deprecated function in Keras 2.5.0 and it has been replaced by `Conv2D` and the `subsample` argument has been replaced by `stride`. You need to either install an older version of Keras like 1.2.2 or modify the model.py code to make it compatible with new Keras.

For more information you may check:

- Keras 1.2.2 (old) Documentation: https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/
- Keras 2.0.5 (new) Documentation: https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/